# Robotframework - returned value of Evaluate keyword does not store all numeric values in variable

Tags: testing, robotframework

I'm trying to compute for a value using Evaluate keyword and it seems not storing the exact whole numeric numbers in the variable ${C1} but it seems to return the exact values I want as per log file.

Here's my sample code.

```
${C1}    Evaluate    1.025**${C_IP_Years_Between}
```

Here's the log:

```
${C1} = BuiltIn . Evaluate 1.025**${C_IP_Years_Between}
Documentation:  
Evaluates the given expression in Python and returns the results.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20180413 21:09:18.343 / 20180413 21:09:18.377 / 00:00:00.034
21:09:18.345    TRACE   Arguments: [ '1.025**11' ]  
21:09:18.376    TRACE   Return: 1.3120866578012655  
21:09:18.377    INFO    ${C1} = 1.3120866578
```

How can I be able to use the whole values being returned above (e.g. 1.3120866578012655)

Answer (score 1):

The robot variable `${C1}` is a float, so it retains all of the precision. The log statement is simply not showing all of the digits.

You can see all of the digits if you explicitly convert the value to a string. In the following example, the test should pass:

```
*** Variables ***
${C_IP_Years_Between}  11

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${C1}=   Evaluate  1.025**${C_IP_Years_Between}
    ${C1f}=  Evaluate  '{0:.16f}'.format($c1)
    Should be equal as strings  ${C1f}  1.3120866578012655
```

Comment: tried doing the one you sample above. it seems to still not able to get the whole significant values.

`KEYWORD ${C1f} = BuiltIn . Evaluate '{0:.16f}'.format(${C1})
Documentation: 
Evaluates the given expression in Python and returns the results.

10:33:39.621 TRACE Arguments: [ "'{0:.16f}'.format(1.3120866578)" ] 
10:33:39.640 TRACE Return: b'1.3120866577999999' 
10:33:39.641 INFO ${C1f} = 1.3120866577999999

Should Be Equal As Strings ${C1f}, 1.3120866578012655
FAIL 1.3120866577999999 != 1.3120866578012655`

Comment: also tried to assert the ${C1} to check if it really contains the whole value but it still do not passed.

`KEYWORD BuiltIn . Should Be Equal As Strings ${C1}, 1.3120866578012655
Documentation: 
Fails if objects are unequal after converting them to strings.

Start / End / Elapsed: 20180416 11:08:38.660 / 20180416 11:08:38.675 / 00:00:00.015
11:08:38.660 TRACE Arguments: [ 1.3120866578012655 | '1.3120866578012655' ] 
11:08:38.660 INFO Argument types are:
<type 'float'>
<type 'unicode'> 
11:08:38.660 FAIL 1.3120866578 != 1.3120866578012655`

Comment: @JohnSigua: well, of course the code in your first comment is going to fail. You're comparing `1.312...999` to `1.312...655`. As you can see from the trace, `C1F` contains the `...999` value, just like as it shows in the trace.

Comment: @JohnSigua: in the second case you're relying on robot's default conversion of the float to a string, which is going to have a different precision. The point is, you need to explicitly convert it to whatever precision you want. Again, the precision is there because the value is a float, not a string. The only problem is that you're relying on robot's default conversion to a string for logging purposes.